# How to pass context to forEach() anonymous function

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

What's the modern and correct way to pass the `this` context to an anonymous forEach function?

```
function Chart() {

  this.draw = function(data) {
     data.forEach(function(value) {
       //do something with values
       console.log(this); //question: how to get Chart instead of global scope?
     )};
  });

};
```

Comment: @GalMarrgalit - Please do not add deprecated tags on question edits! :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Store the current `this` in some other variable in `Chart` like this

```
function Chart() {
    var self = this;
    this.draw = function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(value) {
            //do something with values
            console.log(self);
        });
    }
};
```

Also, you can pass the `this` like the following, as [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) accepts `this`

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

For example,

```
this.draw = function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(value) {
        //do something with values
        console.log(this);
    }, this); // Pass the current object as the second parameter
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use `self` instead of `that`, which seems too ambiguous to me.

Comment: Haha nice one :) Always seems like a personal preference these days, though. So it really depends on what you find comfortable to use.

Comment: @RB-Develop My other side is Python, so I am also comfortable with `self` :)

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks. Any comments on the difference between passing this and using bind (see my own answer)?

Comment: @MMacdonald Nothing much, except that [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) will create a new function and I don't think that can access the enclosed variables (Not sure about this, have to check). BTW, +1 to you, that didn't strike me at first :)

Comment: @MMacdonald Okay, just confirmed. It can even access the enclosed variables. So, the only difference is, it creates new function.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks for such an informed answer.

Answer (score 7):

Adding in my own answer (use **bind**):

```
this.draw = function(data) {
   data.forEach(function(value) {
     //do something with values
     console.log(this); //question: how to get Chart instead of global scope?
   }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: youre missing a parens somewhere