# How do I keep from losing 'this' context in a JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, lodash, bluebird

Here is a sample of my code:

```
function QueueService() {
    var key = Config.get("AWS.accessKeyID");
    var secret = Config.get("AWS.secretKey");
    var credentials = new AWS.Credentials(key, secret, sessionToken = null);

    this._sqs = new Promise.promisifyAll(new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05', region: "us-west-2", endpoint: "sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", credentials: credentials}));
}

QueueService.prototype.FillBirdQueue = function(birds) {
    var self = this;

    birds.forEach(function(bird_batch) {
        var params = {
            Entries: bird_batch,
            QueueUrl: Config.get("AWS-Queue.Birds")
        };

        return self._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);
    });
};
```

If I omit the `var self = this;` and call `return this._sqs.sendMessageBatchAsync(params);` I get an error because `_.sqs` is undefined. It would appear that `this` has changed and the only way around it is to save it for later using `var self = this;`.

I feel like there's a better way of going about this, but I'm not entirely sure how to use the tools at my disposal. I'm currently using Bluebird and Lodash, both of which support binding. In the past, I've passed `this` by executing the following in Bluebird:

```
somethingAsync().bind(this).then(function(result){});
```

I haven't been able to use this pattern because I'm not doing anything async at first. I'm only calling one promise and need to be able to access the variable I defined in my constructor to do so.

I'm overlooking something..what can it be?

Comment: Using the second parameter to `forEach` is probably the cleanest way of doing it. See [How to pass context to forEach() anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814097/how-to-pass-context-to-foreach-anonymous-function).

Comment: You could use `bind`, but there's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it.

Comment: Had to reindent your code... I was stuck for ages thinking you meant the value of `this` was different _before_ and _after_ the `foreach` loop - not during :)

Comment: The better question would be: *Why do you `return` promises from `forEach` callback?* What were you actually going to do with them?

Comment: Why are you doing `new Promise.promsiifyAll` -_-?

Comment: Did you mean to use `Promise.each` or `Promise.map` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Would you be kind enough to explain my error, sir? Re: ```new Promise.promisfyAll```

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thanks for helping out. This wasn't a good morning apparently, I completely lost track of where I was and realized that I was inside of a loop. Sorry all!

Comment: @sean feel free to come to chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript