# Recursive method call on es2015 class method transpiled with babel

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, babeljs, electron

I'm having problems when i try to call a instance method recursively.

The code looks as follows:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import fsWatcher from 'filewatcher';
import path  from 'path';

export default class SearchService {
initializeFileWatcher(foldersToWatch) {
    let result = fsWatcher();
    for (var i = 0; i < foldersToWatch.length; i++) {
        result.add(foldersToWatch[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

  getFilesFromDirectoriesRecursively(directories, fileExtension) {
    let result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
        var dir = directories[i];
        var list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
        list.forEach(function (file) {
            file = dir + '/' + file;
            var stat = fs.statSync(file);
            if (stat && stat.isDirectory())
                result = result.concat(this.getFilesFromDirectoriesRecursively([file], fileExtension).bind(this));
            else
            if (path.extname(file) === fileExtension)
                result.push(file);
        });
    }
    return result;
}

getFilesFromDirectory(directory, fileExtension) {
    var result = [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(directory);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       if (files[i].endsWith(fileExtension))
           result.push(files[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

The code get transpiled with babel-es2015 and runs on a electron app environment. No when I try to call the method *getFilesFromDirectoriesRecursively* inside itself the transpiled code get in troubles because of the *this* which point to the instance in es2015 but not in the transpiled code.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: It's not transpilation issue - `this` does not refer to what you think it does there, since you use it within an anonymous function. Read through http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/251311

Comment: `How can I get around this problem?`. By changing `list.forEach(function (file) {` to `list.forEach(file => {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem. As @zerkms mentioned is was using the *this* keyword false. I tried to bind *this* with the `.bind` keyword what does not work with anonymous functions.

So I applied the the solution described here: [How to pass context to forEach() anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814097/how-to-pass-context-to-foreach-anonymous-function)

```
list.forEach( (file) => {
            file = dir + '/' + file;
            let stat = fs.statSync(file);
            if (stat && stat.isDirectory())
                result = result.concat(this.getFilesFromDirectoriesRecursively([file], fileExtension));
            else
            if (path.extname(file) === fileExtension)
                result.push(file);
        }, this);
```

Now its passing the *this* to the closure on the forEach function call

## Edit:

It's not necessary to pass this because the arrow function is doing this.

```
list.forEach( (file) => {
        file = dir + '/' + file;
        let stat = fs.statSync(file);
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory())
            result = result.concat(this.getFilesFromDirectoriesRecursively([file], fileExtension));
        else
        if (path.extname(file) === fileExtension)
            result.push(file);
});
```

Comment: passing the context here is unnecessary - just the change to ES6 arrow syntax should be sufficient to fix the problem